# How to check an eitem is present in which array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, search

I have two 3 unique arrays:

```
const a =["b","c","d"];
const b = ["ab","cd","ef"]
const c = ["abc", "cde","fgh"]
```

with `array.includes("ab")` we can findout that it is in `b` array. but If we take `abc` and want to search which arrayname it is present in?

How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```js
const a =["b","c","d"];
const b = ["ab","cd","ef"]
const c = ["abc", "cde","fgh"]

const find = (needle, haystack) => Object.entries(haystack).find(([k,v])=>v.includes(needle))[0];
console.log(find('ab', {a, b, c}))
console.log(find('abc', {a, b, c}))
```

of course, this returns a string, which is almost useless to then access the array in a meaningful way - but this does answer the question